# How to avoid encoding the key of request parameters being encoding

Tags: playframework

I'm trying to send a http request using WS.url() with a action receive a custom class parameter like

```
public static void add(@Valid MyPage info) {...}
```

There is a Map in MyPage

```
@Required
public Map<String, String> content = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

But When I try to send a request with

```
WS.url().setParameter("info.content[name]","mynameis");
```

The action got no parameter and request's querystring convert info.content[name] into ...%5Bname%5D...
I checked the WS.createQueryString and found it will encode all key and value. Any way to avoid that?

UPDATE:

I changed it to info.content.name, and it works

Comment: Please state your solution as answer and mark it as resolved so that all know there is a solution for that found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed it to the "info.content.name" form, and it works.
But still don't know how to avoid the "obj[xx]" problem.